# Keras callback on_epoch_end throws error (Nonetype has no len())

Tags: validation, tensorflow, keras, callback, runtime-error

I'm training a lot of neural networks using hyperopt at the moment. Sometimes it runs perfectly through, sometimes not and I don't understand why. It refers to the validation data, but that's always the same. I don't use any k-fold CV yet. The parameters stored in the dictionary setup 'Monitor', 'Patience', 'MinDelta', 'Epochs' and 'BatchSize' stay unchanged too. As you can see below, shuffle is also set to False. I've just tried to train the network manually with the same hyperparameters and it went through. GPU VRAM should be enough because I trained larger networks without problems (more neurons, higher batch size). Does someone have any suggestions or guesses what could lead to this error?

Here are some relevant code snippets:

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor=setup['Monitor'], patience=setup['Patience'],mode='min',
                                   restore_best_weights=True,min_delta=setup['MinDelta']) 

history = autoencoder.fit(trainx, trainy, epochs = setup['Epochs'], batch_size = setup['BatchSize'],
                               validation_data=(valx,valy),callbacks=[early_stopping],verbose=0,shuffle=False)
```

Used parameters of the last error that was shown:

```
{'AFunction': 'relu', 'BatchNorm': False, 'BatchSize': 56, 'Bottleneck': 16, 'Dataset': 'ml100k',
 'Date': '2020-03-14__22_46_30', 'DecNeurons': 480, 'Decay': 0.0006340241989020302,
 'Dropout': 0.0003539460040469268, 'EncNeurons': 256, 'Epochs': 100, 'ID': 3,
 'LR': 0.3869023252696237, 'Layers': 4, 'Metric': 'RMSE', 'MinDelta': 0.01,
 'Monitor': 'val_root_mean_squared_error', 'MP': True, 'Noise': 0.02, 'Normalize': False,
 'Optimizer': 'adam', 'Patience': 25, 'RDigits': 5, 'Split': 'Movie', 'WeightInit': 0,
 'Neurons': [480, 408, 328, 256, 16, 256, 328, 408, 480], 'NeuronSum': 2960,
 'Loss': <function MMSE at 0x000001DED8DD60D0>, 'IO': 943}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-3-3d2f96200fbe>", line 26, in <module>
    best = fmin(fn=ae,space=parameterspace,algo=algo,trials = bayes_trials,max_evals=5000)

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\fmin.py", line 482, in fmin
    show_progressbar=show_progressbar,

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\base.py", line 686, in fmin
    show_progressbar=show_progressbar,

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\fmin.py", line 509, in fmin
    rval.exhaust()

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\fmin.py", line 330, in exhaust
    self.run(self.max_evals - n_done, block_until_done=self.asynchronous)

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\fmin.py", line 286, in run
    self.serial_evaluate()

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\fmin.py", line 165, in serial_evaluate
    result = self.domain.evaluate(spec, ctrl)

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\base.py", line 894, in evaluate
    rval = self.fn(pyll_rval)

  File "<ipython-input-1-5d0cd446e015>", line 229, in ae
    validation_data=(valx,valy),callbacks=[early_stopping],verbose=0,shuffle=False)

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 728, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 372, in fit
    prefix='val_')

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\contextlib.py", line 88, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 685, in on_epoch
    self.callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 298, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 1238, in on_epoch_end
    self.model.set_weights(self.best_weights)

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1322, in set_weights
    if len(params) != len(weights):

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Used environment:

```
(tf2) C:\Users\Admin>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf2:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_tflow_select             2.1.0                       gpu
absl-py                   0.8.1                    py36_0
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py36_0
alembic                   1.3.2                      py_0    conda-forge
appdirs                   1.4.3                      py_1    conda-forge
asn1crypto                1.3.0                    py36_0
astor                     0.8.0                    py36_0
astroid                   2.3.3                    py36_0
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0
babel                     2.8.0                      py_0
backcall                  0.1.0                    py36_0
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
bayesian-optimization     1.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    3.1.0                    py36_0
ca-certificates           2020.1.1                      0    anaconda
certifi                   2019.11.28               py36_0    anaconda
cffi                      1.13.2           py36h7a1dbc1_0
chardet                   3.0.4                 py36_1003
click                     7.0                        py_0    conda-forge
cloudpickle               1.2.2                      py_0
colorama                  0.4.3                      py_0
configparser              3.7.3                    py36_1    conda-forge
cryptography              2.8              py36h7a1dbc1_0
cudatoolkit               10.0.130                      0
cudnn                     7.6.5                cuda10.0_0
cycler                    0.10.0           py36h009560c_0
databricks-cli            0.9.1                      py_0    conda-forge
decorator                 4.4.1                      py_0
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0
docker-py                 4.1.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
docker-pycreds            0.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
docutils                  0.15.2                   py36_0
entrypoints               0.3                      py36_0
flask                     1.1.1                      py_1    conda-forge
floweaver                 2.0.0a5                    py_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.9.1                ha9979f8_1
future                    0.18.2                   pypi_0    pypi
gast                      0.2.2                    py36_0
gitdb2                    2.0.6                      py_0    conda-forge
gitpython                 3.0.5                      py_0    conda-forge
google-pasta              0.1.8                      py_0
gorilla                   0.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
grpcio                    1.16.1           py36h351948d_1
h5py                      2.9.0            py36h5e291fa_0
hdf5                      1.10.4               h7ebc959_0
hyperopt                  0.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       58.2                 ha66f8fd_1
idna                      2.8                      py36_0
imagesize                 1.2.0                      py_0
importlib_metadata        1.3.0                    py36_0
intel-openmp              2019.4                      245
ipykernel                 5.1.3            py36h39e3cac_1
ipython                   7.11.1           py36h39e3cac_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py36_0
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0
isort                     4.3.21                   py36_0
itsdangerous              1.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.15.2                   py36_0
jinja2                    2.10.3                     py_0
joblib                    0.14.1                     py_0
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
jsonschema                3.2.0                    py36_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py36_7
jupyter_client            5.3.4                    py36_0
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py36_0
jupyter_core              4.6.1                    py36_0

keras                     2.3.1            py36h21ff451_0    conda-forge

keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_0
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1
keyring                   20.0.0                   py36_0
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py36ha925a31_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3            py36he774522_0
libgpuarray               0.7.6             hfa6e2cd_1003    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libprotobuf               3.11.2               h7bd577a_0
libsodium                 1.0.16               h9d3ae62_0
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
mako                      1.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
markdown                  3.1.1                    py36_0
markupsafe                1.1.1            py36he774522_0
matplotlib                3.1.1            py36hc8f65d3_0
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py36_1
mistune                   0.8.4            py36he774522_0
mkl                       2019.4                      245
mkl-service               2.3.0            py36hb782905_0
mkl_fft                   1.0.15           py36h14836fe_0
mkl_random                1.1.0            py36h675688f_0
mlflow                    1.5.0                    py36_1    conda-forge
more-itertools            8.0.2                      py_0
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py36_0
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py36_0
networkx                  2.2                      pypi_0    pypi
notebook                  6.0.2                    py36_0
numpy                     1.17.4           py36h4320e6b_0
numpy-base                1.17.4           py36hc3f5095_0
numpydoc                  0.9.2                      py_0
openssl                   1.1.1                he774522_0    anaconda
opt_einsum                3.1.0                      py_0
packaging                 20.0                       py_0
palettable                3.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pandas                    0.25.3           py36ha925a31_0
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py36_1
parso                     0.5.2                      py_0
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py36_0
pip                       19.3.1                   py36_0
plotly                    3.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0
prometheus_flask_exporter 0.12.1                     py_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            2.0.10                     py_0
protobuf                  3.11.2           py36h33f27b4_0
psutil                    5.6.7            py36he774522_0
pycodestyle               2.5.0                    py36_0
pycparser                 2.19                     py36_0
pyflakes                  2.1.1                    py36_0
pygments                  2.5.2                      py_0
pygpu                     0.7.6           py36hc8d92b1_1000    conda-forge
pylint                    2.4.4                    py36_0
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                   py36_0
pyparsing                 2.4.6                      py_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py36h6538335_2
pyreadline                2.1                      py36_1
pyrsistent                0.15.6           py36he774522_0
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py36_0
python                    3.6.10               h9f7ef89_0
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0
python-editor             1.0.4                      py_0    conda-forge
pytz                      2019.3                     py_0
pywin32                   227              py36he774522_1
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0                    py36_0
pywinpty                  0.5.7                    py36_0
pyyaml                    5.3              py36hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
pyzmq                     18.1.0           py36ha925a31_0
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
qtawesome                 0.6.0                      py_0
qtconsole                 4.6.0                      py_1
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0
querystring_parser        1.2.4                      py_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.22.0                   py36_1
retrying                  1.3.3                    py36_2
rope                      0.14.0                     py_0
scikit-learn              0.22.1           py36h6288b17_0
scipy                     1.3.2            py36h29ff71c_0
seaborn                   0.10.0                     py_0    anaconda
send2trash                1.5.0                    py36_0
setuptools                44.0.0                   py36_0
simplejson                3.17.0           py36hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
sip                       4.19.8           py36h6538335_0
six                       1.13.0                   py36_0
smmap2                    2.0.5                      py_0    conda-forge
snowballstemmer           2.0.0                      py_0
sphinx                    2.3.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.3                      py_0
spyder                    3.3.6                    py36_0
spyder-kernels            0.5.2                    py36_0
sqlalchemy                1.3.12           py36hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.30.1               he774522_0
sqlparse                  0.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
tabulate                  0.8.6                      py_0    conda-forge

tensorboard               2.0.0              pyhb38c66f_1
tensorflow                2.0.0           gpu_py36hfdd5754_0
tensorflow-base           2.0.0           gpu_py36h390e234_0
tensorflow-estimator      2.0.0              pyh2649769_0
tensorflow-gpu            2.0.0                h0d30ee6_0

termcolor                 1.1.0                    py36_1
terminado                 0.8.3                    py36_0
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0
theano                    1.0.4           py36h6538335_1001    conda-forge
tornado                   6.0.3            py36he774522_0
tqdm                      4.43.0                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py36_0
typed-ast                 1.4.0            py36he774522_0
urllib3                   1.25.7                   py36_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_1
vs2015_win-64             14.0.25420          h55c1224_11
waitress                  1.4.1                      py_0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py36_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py36_1
websocket-client          0.57.0                   py36_0    conda-forge
werkzeug                  0.16.0                     py_0
wheel                     0.33.6                   py36_0
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py36_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0                    py36_0
wincertstore              0.2              py36h7fe50ca_0
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
wrapt                     1.11.2           py36he774522_0
yaml                      0.2.2                hfa6e2cd_1    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.1                h33f27b4_3
zipp                      0.6.0                      py_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_3
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is cause by a bug (that is yet to be fixed) that happens when the training only sees a worsening performance.

The line `self.best_weights` (initialized to None (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/295ad2781683835be974faba0a191528d8079768/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py#L1190) is only overwritten with weight values if at the end of the epoch (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/295ad2781683835be974faba0a191528d8079768/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py#L1221) if the performance has improved.

If the data/hyperparameter configuration is such that the the performance only worsens, and you've set `restore_best_weights=True`, then it calls `self.model.set_weights(self.best_weights)` with `None` and that's where the error is raised.